# How can I pass an object reference into the constructor of another object in mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've looked around here, and pretty much everywhere else I can think of, but I can't find a solution to my problem, so here it is:

In my current project, I have a class that instantiates an object as part of its constructor, passing itself in so the child object will have a reference to its parent. Ideally, anyway. What ends up happening, though, is that the child gets a static view of the parent object. 
Here's an example of what I mean:

```
var myParentClass = new Class({
    name: '',
    child: null,

    initialize: function(){
        this.name = 'fred';
        this.child = new myChildClass({ parent: this });
        this.name = 'george';
        this.setFeedback('feedback1');
        this.child.setFeedback('feedback2');
    },

    setFeedback: function(id){
        $(id).set('html',this.name);    
    }

    });

var myChildClass = new Class({

    Implements: [Options],

    options: {
        parent: null,
    },

    initialize: function(options){
      this.setOptions(options);   
    },

    setFeedback: function(id){
        this.options.parent.setFeedback(id);       
    }
});


var a = new myParentClass();
```

​In this example, feedback1's contents would be 'george', and we'd expect that feedback2's contents would be the same. However, it's not. It's 'fred' because it has a static view of the parent, whose name property changed AFTER the object was passed in as a parameter.  For your further enjoyment, I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/the_zenith/YGHPQ/5/%20%27jsfiddle%27) to illustrate the point.

So the question is this: Is there any way I can get a child object to have a real actual reference to its parent, or am I doomed to only ever have a static view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because the `setOptions` method dereferences properties via an Object.merge into a new Object, cloning them into the local prototype of the child instance.

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.Extras.js#L110

change the constructor function to accept another argument, parent and statically store `this.parent = parent`, then call from that.

incidentally, don't use `.parent` as this is kind of reserved for when you extend classes in mootools :)

Comment: Awesome. That fixed it right up. In my real project, I use 'owner' rather than parent.

Comment: Actually, when I do that, I get the following error:
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` with the stack being a whole bunch of calls to `cloneOf
Object.extend.clone`

Comment: This happens both when I place the owner reference before options or after, not that it would matter either way.

Comment: Never mind. I found the error. I was propagating the owner to the parent constructor, which was causing a big infinite loop when mootools was extending it down. I just built it directly into the child class and now it's done. Basically, ClassA was building an object of type ClassC, which extends ClassB. The ClassB constructor handled storing the reference to the ClassA object, which the ClassC object was to inherit. mootools and/or js didn't like this and threw a fit.